# Swift: NotificationCenter's addObserver closure keeps getting triggered constantly

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I have an `AVPlayer` to play an MP3 stream. I added an observer for when the stream is ended, the trouble is the closure seems to be stuck in a loop after it's triggered for the first time.

```
//// Variables 
private var periodicTimeObserverToken: Any?
private var finishObserverToken: Any?

//// Setting up the player
self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: filePath)
self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem)
removePeriodicTimeObserver()
removePlayerFinishedObserver()
addPeriodicTimeObserver()
addPlayerFinishedObserver()

///
private func addPeriodicTimeObserver() {
    periodicTimeObserverToken = self.player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTime(seconds: 0.05, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC)), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { [weak self] (CMTime) -> Void in
        if self?.player?.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay {
            /// Calling some other external delegates
        }
    }
}

private func removePeriodicTimeObserver() {
    if let token = periodicTimeObserverToken {
        self.player?.removeTimeObserver(token)
        periodicTimeObserverToken = nil
    }
}

private func addPlayerFinishedObserver() {
    finishObserverToken = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player?.currentItem, queue: .main) { [weak self] _ in
        self?.player?.pause()
    }
}

private func removePlayerFinishedObserver() {
    if let _ = finishObserverToken, let _player = self.player, let _playerCurrentItem = _player.currentItem {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(_player)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(_playerCurrentItem)
        self.finishObserverToken = nil
    }
}

public func endSession() {
    player?.pause()
    removePeriodicTimeObserver()
    removePlayerFinishedObserver()
    playerItem = nil
    player = nil
}
```

The parent class calls `endSession()` after stream reaches the end, but `self?.player?.pause()` from `addPlayerFinishedObserver()` gets called non stop, anything inside the `addObserver` closure gets called continuously.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove its token inside the closure:

```
private func addPlayerFinishedObserver() {
    finishObserverToken = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player?.currentItem, queue: .main) { [weak self] _ in
        self?.player?.pause()
        if let token = self?.finishObserverToken {
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(token)
        }
    }
}
```